# How to execute a function at certain time and day with Flask and Python?

Tags: python, flask, slack, slack-api

I was wondering if it was possible to have a web service running on Flask to execute a function at a certain time every day.

I'm making a Slack bot with Flask and Python, and I want the bot to send out a reminder every day at 6:00 to a channel.

Is it possible to keep track of the current time continuously, and only perform an action once the current time equals a set time?

Answer (score 1):

You could, but that is not a good way of doing it. Your operating system almost certainly has this functionality built-in; on unix-like systems for example you would use cron.

Comment: I tried using an APScheduler cron job, but the problem with that was that it had to be run as a separate job, or else the cron jobs would be blocking the Flask tasks from running. I'd rather keep everything in one project.